# How to Download Folder from iCloud.com

Tags: file, download, icloud

i have many files in a **folder "ABC"** that stored **only** in **www.icloud.com**.

My Question is How to Download All of My Files from folder "ABC" ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here is a workaround I use:

- Use the "Files" app on my iPhone/iPad.
- Long press the folder, and choose **compress, and a "xxx.zip" file will be created**.
- Use the iCloud web to download the "xxx.zip" file.
- Unzip the file.

Comment: if I'm correct it downloads folder on the iPhone, then compresses it and uploads lmao,
just checked on my iPad and there is huge network activity during "your workaround",
really want to be wrong but man, that's apple :(

Answer (score 1):

You have to select each file individually and download them. You can download multiple files under the same folder, but if you have multiple subfolders, then it's gonna take some time. You can't download folders.

I wonder if there's an app, which does all of this for you. I would gladly use it myself.